# PHP XML : html_entity_decode and How to display ampersand?

Tags: php, xml

How I display (in output) ampersand (**&**) in XML file which generated from PHP DOM ?
I use following code to generate XML file

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8', );
$document = $dom->appendChild(
    $dom->createElement('DOCUMENT')
);
$order = $document->appendChild(
    $dom->createElement('ORDER')
);
$oh = $order->appendChild(
    $dom->createElement('OH')
);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($xml_oh_element_array); $i++) {
    $reportVariable = $oh->appendChild(
          $dom->createElement($xml_oh_element_array[$i])
    );
    $reportVariable->appendChild(
          $dom->createTextNode($xml_oh_element_data_array[$i])
   );
}
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->save('Order'.$order_data_xml["order_id"].'.xml');
```

Its generate XML file, but display **`&amp;`** in place of **&**. I want **&**, not **`&amp;`**

Also I use `html_entity_decode` for support european countries latters but its not working with some latters like `ÅÄÖ`